# Given $\gamma(t)$ a $\mathcal{C}^1$ path on $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, why is it true that $|\gamma(t)|$ is also $\mathcal{C}^1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is continuously differentiable, there is a proof I saw involved using the fact that $s(t)=|\gamma(t)|$ must also continuously differentiable but I cannot quite convince myself why this is the case. (Of course, the differentiability of $s(t)$ is in the sense of real-variables.)

So we want to show that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\gamma(t+h)|-|\gamma(t)|}{h}$ exist given $\gamma(t)$ is continuously complex differentiable. I have thought about using a bit of triangle inequality and manipulation, one can obtain $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\gamma(t+h)|-|\gamma(t)|}{h}\leq \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)|}{h}$$

Now I am a bit stuck, I think we can say since $\gamma(t)\in \mathcal{C}^1$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)|}{h}$ must exist, but what is next?

I can see the statement to be true but I wanted to construct something that is more concrete.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute value function from $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ into $\Bbb R$ is real-differentiable everywhere, and its derivative is continuous; in other words, it's a class $C^1$ function. So, $t\mapsto|\gamma(t)|$ is the composition of two class $C^1$ functions, and thereforeit is a class $C^1$ function too..